# .htaccess force HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been struggling for a while to find a method of using .htaccess to force HTTPS on my website. Any way I've tried has resulted in a redirect loop. I found a PHP alternative and amended it to suit my webserver, but I'd like the .htaccess equivalent if anybody could help.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] != "https") {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    $location = "https://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    header("Location: $location");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. However my root domain's document root is in a subdirectory so it redirects to https://example.com/example.com - would you know how to fix?

Comment: ok try: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]` as last line in this rule.

Comment: This is pretty much what people all over the Internet telling you to do for forcing https. However, every time I do that, my whole website becomes FORBIDDEN or You have no permission to view. something like that... What am I doing wrong? I just want to know if you have any idea before I post a question on this.

Comment: @ThN: Yes please post a new question as your config/setup might be different.