# .htaccess, force HTTPS and remove index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I know that there are multiple posts, but I cannot solve with other answers.

I did try this: [htaccess force www and remove index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573195/htaccess-force-www-and-remove-index-php) and [.htaccess force HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709820/htaccess-force-https) without success.

My site has an index.php that perform routers. So a link "/about" in reality is managed from index.php (to remove in the link).

This is my current htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

It works perfectly for the index.php (in effect it removes the index.php and rewrite the URL).

It can rewrite from `example.com` to `https://www.example.com` (**and this is ok, I want this!**). But it **doesn't** rewrite from **http://www.example.com** to **https://www.example.com.**

For example, a link as "http://www.example.com/this/is/a/not/link/secure" remains as is. **But I want a redirect to "https://www.example.com/this/is/a/not/link/secure"**

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Per anubhava answer, this is the new entire htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!localhost$|127\.0\.0\.1$)(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Now it rewrite a `http://www.example.com/apiv2/member-card?id=12` in `https://www.example.com/www.example.com//?id=12`   with a double domain.....
Same as `http://example.com/apiv2/member-card?id=12` got rewritten in `https://www.example.com/www.example.com//?id=12`

Comment: How about using proxy pass? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130303/apache-config-how-to-proxypass-http-requests-to-https#16146460

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule needs to have `[OR]` clause to redirect for both conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!localhost$|127\.0\.0\.1$)(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thank you. But with your rules, this link: http://www.example.com/apiv2/member-card?id=12      get redirect to https://www.example.com//?id=12  it removes everything in the middle

Comment: No this rule doesn't remove anything from URI as I am using `%{REQUEST_URI}` which is full URI. You may have other rules in your .htaccess, can you post your full .htaccess

Comment: thank you. Entire htaccess in my original question. Thank you very much

Comment: Oh you have rules in wrong order. See my updated answer with full .htaccess. Test it after you clear your browser cache.

Comment: unfortunately not. With your .htaccess every request goes in 404 and doesn't redirect to https version :(

Comment: In that case you have some other config/code issue. Exact same code from this answer works great for every condition on my Apache.